# Snowflake - Operation in VALUES clause - Invalid expression

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can we get a rational number in a VALUES clause in Snowflake ?

```sql
SELECT * FROM ( 
   VALUES (1/3.0), (2)
) AS  t ;
```

returns :

> SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [1 / 3] in VALUES clause

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is so peculiar it could be characterised as a bug.

Any division that results in a whole number works, but fractions trigger the error message.

The [Documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constructs/values.html) states that:
Each expression must be a constant, or an *expression that can be evaluated as a constant* during compilation of the SQL statement.
*Most simple arithmetic expressions* and string functions can be evaluated at compile time, but most other expressions cannot.

Clearly `(1/3)` should be such a simple arithmetic expression.  The simple workaround is of course to calculate the answer and include as a decimal number:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (0.33333333333333333), (2)) AS T(VAL);
```

On second thought this is not as straight forward as it seems.  If those values are used in a `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` statement, should the data type be `NUMBER(7,6)` or `FLOAT` or something else?  Maybe it is best to be specific in these cases.

The specifics for division etc are documented in [Scale and Precision in Arithmetic Operations](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/operators-arithmetic.html#scale-and-precision-in-arithmetic-operations).

Comment: There are other such areas where this same thing occurs, such as setting a variable to a value.  I recommend checking out the Ideas page of Snowflake Community (https://community.snowflake.com/s/ideas) and search/upvoting or creating a new idea.  I wouldn't classify it as a bug, but it's certainly something that should be more robust.

Answer (score 2):

if you know you have a large number of rational input you want you can just do the math in the select

```
SELECT column1/column2 FROM VALUES (1,3),(2,1);
```

giving:

```
COLUMN1/COLUMN2
0.333333
2.000000
```