# Snowflake Unable to insert multiple rows using insert into having md5 field

Tags: sql, sql-insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bulkinsert

I am adding multiple rows using `INSERT INTO table VALUES` as follows:

```
insert into hub values 
 (md5(md5('test1')) as enc,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as ct, 'DATA_SOURCE_1', 'test1'),
 (md5(md5('test2')) as enc,  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as ct, 'DATA_SOURCE_1', 'test2')
;
```

And I am getting the following error:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 19 unexpected
> 'as'. syntax error line 2 at position 28 unexpected
> 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. syntax error line 2 at position 50 unexpected
> ''DATA_SOURCE_1''. syntax error line 3 at position 19 unexpected 'as'. syntax
> error line 3 at position 28 unexpected 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'. syntax
> error line 3 at position 50 unexpected ''DATA_SOURCE_1''.

I tried to remove the `as` from the subqueries but I got the following error:

> SQL compilation error: Invalid expression [MD5(MD5('test'))] in VALUES
> clause

I know that `md5` should return a value not an expression that's why I used `AS` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems like a bug to me and it's kind of similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58647022/snowflake-operation-in-values-clause-invalid-expression). You can write the insert in a different way however to achieve the same result:

```sql
insert into hub
    select md5(md5('test1')), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'DATA_SOURCE_1', 'test1'
union all
    select md5(md5('test2')), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'DATA_SOURCE_1', 'test2'
```

or alternatively like the following, which may be more concise if you have many rows in the `VALUE` part:

```sql
insert into hub
select
    md5(md5(column1)),
    column2,
    column3,
    column4
from
values
       ('test1', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'DATA_SOURCE_1', 'test1'),
       ('test2', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 'DATA_SOURCE_1', 'test2')
```

Comment: is it the same way with `merge into` ?

Comment: Haven't tried with a merge but shouldn't be too hard to test.